# Remove Special Charactors from Az command Output using Az CLI

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

I'm Trying to get only IP address from below command using Azure cli. But it always coming with extra "".

```
az network nic ip-config list --resource-group "RG_TEST" --nic-name "TEST_NIC6768" --query "[0].privateIpAddress"
```

Output: "10.244.4.4"

Required Output: 10.244.4.4

Comment: Hi, have you checked the answers, do they answer your question? :)

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the output to `|ForEach-Object Trim '"'` to have PowerShell automatically [strip leading and trailing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-7.0) `"`'s from the output:

```
az network nic ip-config list --resource-group "RG_TEST" --nic-name "TEST_NIC6768" --query "[0].privateIpAddress" |ForEach-Object Trim '"'
```

Answer (score 0):

The **`az` CLI outputs *JSON* data by default**, which in the case of a *string* value means that it is output *with enclosing `"..."`*.

**While you can remove those `"` characters *afterwards*, it is better to ask `az` not to include them in the first place**, which you can do with **`--output tsv`** (**`-o tsv`**):

```bash
# Note the addition of `--output tsv`
az network nic ip-config list --output tsv --resource-group "RG_TEST" --nic-name "TEST_NIC6768" --query "[0].privateIpAddress"
```

Note:

- `--output tsv` requests the output in TSV (tab-separated values) form, which in the case of a single string means that it is printed *as-is* (verbatim); aside from not having to remove enclosing `"..."`, this also means that you never need to worry about *unescaping* JSON-escaped characters such as `\` and *embedded* `"`.
- `az` supports additional [output formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/format-output-azure-cli).

---

The quick-and-dirty alternative is to simply remove all `"` chars. with a [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation:

```bash
(
  az network nic ip-config list --resource-group "RG_TEST" --nic-name "TEST_NIC6768" --query "[0].privateIpAddress"
) -replace '"'
```